# Decomposition of multiplication invariant probability measure= $q$Dirac$+(1-q)$Lebesgue

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $\delta_0$ the dirac measure and $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure.

Suppose we have a probability measure $P$ on $[0,1)$ such that is it invariant under the map $T(x)=nx\;\mbox{mod}\; 1$.

Then $P$ can be written as $$q\delta_0+(1-q)\lambda\quad (*)$$ for $q\in[0,1].$

The proof I am reading say starts by noticing that $\phi_n=\int_{0}^1 e^{i2\pi n x}dP(x)=q$, I am ok with this step.

Next, he argues that $P(\{0\})=q$ and conlude the decomposition $(*)$.
Can someone explains why $$P(\{0\})=q\implies (*)\quad?$$

Comment: As stated, this is definitely false.  For example, the Cantor distribution is invariant under the map $x \mapsto 3x$ but it doesn't satisfy a decomposition of the form $(*)$.  An even simpler counterexample is the measure $\frac12 \delta_{1/3} + \frac12 \delta_{2/3}$, which is invariant under $x \mapsto 2x$.

Comment: @Adam OP means invariant under $x \mapsto nx$ for all $n$.